# PHP y XML - Mostrar contenido de XML a través de PHP

Tags: php, xml, wsdl

Desde PHP estoy intentando visualizar el resultado de ejecutar un documento WSDL (que incluye el código XML) y no hay manera. A continuación el detalle de todo cuanto he implementado.

La siguiente imágen es el resultado que debería dar el documento WSDL, basado en un informe creado en SAP BusinessObjects Web Intelligence:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El documento WSDL tiene el siguiente código:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <definitions xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:s0="ServicioWeb_Prueba" xmlns:tns1="dsws.businessobjects.com" targetNamespace="ServicioWeb_Prueba" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="BIServices">
- <types>
- <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="ServicioWeb_Prueba">
- <s:simpleType name="Operator">
- <s:restriction base="s:string">
  <s:enumeration value="EQUAL" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="GREATER" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="GREATER_OR_EQUAL" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="LESS" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="LESS_OR_EQUAL" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="NOT_EQUAL" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="INLIST" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="NOT_INLIST" /> 
  </s:restriction>
  </s:simpleType>
- <s:complexType name="FilterCondition">
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="value" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="operator" type="s0:Operator" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
- <s:complexType name="LovValueIndex">
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="valueofPrompt" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="index" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
- <s:complexType name="DrillFilter">
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="dimension" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="value" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="operator" type="s0:Operator" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
- <s:element name="GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="login" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="password" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="_Fecha_Productiva__lista_" type="s0:FilterCondition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="_Dia_Sem_Prod__lista_" type="s0:FilterCondition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="_Semana_Productiva__lista_" type="s0:FilterCondition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="resetState" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="refresh" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="getFromLatestDocumentInstance" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="getFromUserInstance" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="turnOutputToVTable" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="closeDocument" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="startRow" type="s:int" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="endRow" type="s:int" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:simpleType name="DrillOperation">
- <s:restriction base="s:string">
  <s:enumeration value="UP" /> 
  <s:enumeration value="DOWN" /> 
  </s:restriction>
  </s:simpleType>
- <s:complexType name="DrillPath">
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="from" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="value" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="drillOperation" type="s0:DrillOperation" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
- <s:element name="Drill_WS_Prueba_1">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="login" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="password" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="drillPath" type="s0:DrillPath" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="filter" type="s0:DrillFilter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="resetState" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="refresh" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="getFromLatestDocumentInstance" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="getFromUserInstance" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="turnOutputToVTable" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="closeDocument" type="s:boolean" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="startRow" type="s:int" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="endRow" type="s:int" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:complexType name="TRow">
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="cell" type="s:anyType" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
- <s:complexType name="TTable">
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="s0:TRow" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
- <s:complexType name="THeader">
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="s0:TRow" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
- <s:complexType name="TFooter">
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="s0:TRow" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
- <s:element name="GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1Response">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="table" type="s0:TTable" /> 
  <s:element name="headers" type="s0:THeader" /> 
  <s:element name="footers" type="s0:TFooter" /> 
  <s:element name="user" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="documentation" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="documentname" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="lastrefreshdate" type="s:dateTime" /> 
  <s:element name="creationdate" type="s:dateTime" /> 
  <s:element name="creator" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="isScheduled" type="s:boolean" /> 
  <s:element name="scheduleStartTime" type="s:dateTime" /> 
  <s:element name="scheduleEndTime" type="s:dateTime" /> 
  <s:element name="tableType" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="nbColumns" type="s:int" /> 
  <s:element name="nbLines" type="s:int" /> 
  <s:element name="message" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="Drill_WS_Prueba_1Response">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="table" type="s0:TTable" /> 
  <s:element name="headers" type="s0:THeader" /> 
  <s:element name="footers" type="s0:TFooter" /> 
  <s:element name="user" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="documentation" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="documentname" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="lastrefreshdate" type="s:dateTime" /> 
  <s:element name="creationdate" type="s:dateTime" /> 
  <s:element name="creator" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="isScheduled" type="s:boolean" /> 
  <s:element name="scheduleStartTime" type="s:dateTime" /> 
  <s:element name="scheduleEndTime" type="s:dateTime" /> 
  <s:element name="tableType" type="s:string" /> 
  <s:element name="nbColumns" type="s:int" /> 
  <s:element name="nbLines" type="s:int" /> 
  <s:element name="message" type="s:string" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
- <s:element name="QaaWSHeader">
- <s:complexType>
- <s:sequence>
  <s:element name="sessionID" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="serializedSession" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="ClientType" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="AuditingObjectID" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <s:element name="AuditingObjectName" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  </s:schema>
  </types>
- <message name="GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1SoapIn">
  <part name="parameters" element="s0:GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1" /> 
  <part name="request_header" element="s0:QaaWSHeader" /> 
  </message>
- <message name="GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1SoapOut">
  <part name="parameters" element="s0:GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1Response" /> 
  </message>
- <message name="Drill_WS_Prueba_1SoapIn">
  <part name="parameters" element="s0:Drill_WS_Prueba_1" /> 
  <part name="request_header" element="s0:QaaWSHeader" /> 
  </message>
- <message name="Drill_WS_Prueba_1SoapOut">
  <part name="parameters" element="s0:Drill_WS_Prueba_1Response" /> 
  </message>
- <portType name="BIServicesSoap">
- <operation name="GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1">
  <documentation /> 
  <input message="s0:GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1SoapIn" /> 
  <output message="s0:GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1SoapOut" /> 
  </operation>
- <operation name="Drill_WS_Prueba_1">
  <documentation /> 
  <input message="s0:Drill_WS_Prueba_1SoapIn" /> 
  <output message="s0:Drill_WS_Prueba_1SoapOut" /> 
  </operation>
  </portType>
- <binding name="BIServicesSoap" type="s0:BIServicesSoap">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" /> 
- <operation name="GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1">
  <documentation /> 
  <soap:operation soapAction="ServicioWeb_Prueba/GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1" style="document" /> 
- <input>
- <soap:header message="s0:GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1SoapIn" part="request_header" use="literal">
  <soap:headerfault message="s0:GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1SoapIn" part="request_header" use="literal" /> 
  </soap:header>
  <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters" /> 
  </input>
- <output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </output>
  </operation>
- <operation name="Drill_WS_Prueba_1">
  <documentation /> 
  <soap:operation soapAction="ServicioWeb_Prueba/Drill_WS_Prueba_1" style="document" /> 
- <input>
- <soap:header message="s0:Drill_WS_Prueba_1SoapIn" part="request_header" use="literal">
  <soap:headerfault message="s0:Drill_WS_Prueba_1SoapIn" part="request_header" use="literal" /> 
  </soap:header>
  <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters" /> 
  </input>
- <output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </output>
  </operation>
  </binding>
- <service name="ServicioWeb_Prueba">
  <documentation /> 
- <port name="BIServicesSoap" binding="s0:BIServicesSoap">
  <soap:address location="http://l49fis14:44426/dswsbobje/qaawsservices/queryasaservice/biws?cuid=M1q8tkoAAPUEAWUA1AAAjpX.AgrLLRgAAAA&authType=secEnterprise&locale=es_ES&timeout=60&ConvertAnyType=true" /> 
  </port>
  </service>
  </definitions>
```

Y por último, estoy intentando generar una tabla desde PHP que muestre el mismo resultado que aparece en la primera imágen adjunta:

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$bohostAndPort = 'l49fis14:44426'; //for example servername:8080 for default tomcat host
$boUser = 'usuario';
$boPwd = 'contrasenya';
$boWsdlCUID = 'M1q8tkoAAPUEAWUA1AAAjpX.AgrLLRgAAAA'; //get this from the bi service publishing tool in webi
$boWSName = 'ServicioWeb_Prueba'; //get this from the bi service publishing tool in webi


//Ejemplo con el informe "DIA_DE_LA_SEMANA" con 1 petición de orden "aaaass"
$client=new nusoap_client("http://l49fis14:44426/dswsbobje/qaawsservices/biws?WSDL=1&cuid=M1q8tkoAAPUEAWUA1AAAjpX.AgrLLRgAAAA",true);
$err = $client->getError(); 

if ($err) { 
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>'; 
} 

$params = '<GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1 xmlns="'.$boWSName.'"><login>'.$boUser.'</login><password>'.$boPwd.'</password></GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1>';

$result = $client->call('GetReportBlock_WS_Prueba_1',$params);

// Check for a fault
if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    // Check for errors
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        var_dump($err);
    } else {
        // Display the result
        echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
//      var_dump($result);
//       echo '<hr>';

echo '<table border=1>';
        foreach( $result["TTable"]["row"] as $key => $value )
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            PrintColumn1($value);
            PrintColumn2($value);
            PrintColumn3($value);
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
}}

function PrintColumn1($array)
{
if(is_array($array))
{
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
if(is_array($value))
{
PrintColumn1($value);
}
else
{
if($key == '0')
echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
}
}
}
}

function PrintColumn2($array)
{
if(is_array($array))
{
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
if(is_array($value))
{
PrintColumn2($value);
}
else
{
if($key == '1')
echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
}
}
}
}

function PrintColumn3($array)
{
if(is_array($array))
{
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
if(is_array($value))
{
PrintColumn3($value);
}
else
{
if($key == '2')
echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
}
}
}
}
```

En las siguientes líneas:
    $boUser = 'usuario';
    $boPwd = 'contrasenya';

Donde aparece 'usuario' y 'contrasenya' indico el nombre y contraseña del usuario que utilizo para iniciar sesión en Business Objects.

Cuando ejecuto el PHP por navegador, aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> Result
>
> Notice:  Undefined index: TTable in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\leerBO\prueba2_soap.php on line 40
>
> Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\leerBO\prueba2_soap.php on line 40

Y es que sinceramente no sé cómo indicarle que me recupere los valores de: "_Fecha_Productiva__lista_","_Dia_Sem_Prod__lista_" y "_Semana_Productiva__lista_". Porque no tengo mucho conocimiento de XML.

Por favor, ¿podéis ayudarme?

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos,
Oscar

Comment: ¿Los guiones `-`  a la izquierda son parte de tu XML?

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, no, esos guiones no son parte de mi código. Mi código fuente está sin esos guiones. No sé porque se incluyeron en el post.